# sum max value across multiple non-adjacent columns

Tags: excel

In excel, is there a neat way (e.g. using arrays ?) to do this ? I have 3 non-adjacent columns all with numbers, and I want the sum of the max value in each row; I could only arrive at this:

```
=SUM(MAX(E23, H23, K23),MAX(E24, H24, K24),  MAX(E25, H25, K25), 
MAX(E26, H26, K26), MAX(E27, H27, K27), MAX(E28, H28, K28))
```

any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I doubt this is possible without a helper column that stores the max for each row that you sum at the end, or VBA if you do not want the helper column.

Comment: I'm sure @Scott is right, but just for interest what is in the columns in between (F,G etc.)?

Comment: thanks both; helper column def the way forward; the intervening data golf score data; each hole is in a separate row, and then gross, net, & pts scores repeat per person in the columns